# Drupal views: list referenced nodes except the one used as contextual filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i have the following case: I am building a website that has information on filmmakers and their films. I have a node type for the filmmaker, with biographical content, etc and another one for the films, with a field 'author' that references one or more of the filmmakers (since one film may have been made by several of them).

I also have a views block called 'filmography' that lists all the films whose author is the filmmaker (node) the user is seeing. Setting this up with a contextual filter was quite easy.

But now I want to present in this block along with the film name, all the filmmakers that may have made the film ('author' field in the film node) and that are different from the filmmaker being viewed. Displaying all the filmmaker nodes referenced by the author field is immediate, but I want to remove the filmmaker that I am using in the contextual filter. The goal is to get something like this:

**Filmmaker 1**

- *Movie 1*
- *Movie 2* (with **Filmmaker 2**)
- *Movie 3*

I have the notion that this might be done using views php and filtering the node references returned, but I wonder if there is an easier solution for that...

Thanks

Update: I have managed to get a result using the Views Field View module, passing the list of referenced nodes (filmmakers) as a contextual filter (node ID) and then adding another contextual filter (node ID as well) as an exclusion, and getting the default value of the letter from 'node id from URL option' (that is, from filmmaker's page the filmography view is embedded in). Keeping the question open for a while to get other, possibly more efficient, alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read your question, the Views Field View module popped into my mind as the obvious solution (then I saw your edit). I think this will still be your best bet. Definitely avoid using php fields as that is not a good practice in general from a security standpoint. If you are concerned about efficiency/performance, then you should just use views caching setting under the advanced options. Seems like this option is always looked over.

If you are looking for alternative options, one might be to use rendered nodes as your View style instead of fields, then use Display Suite to generate additional display modes beyond "Default" and "Teaser," create a view with the filters, then use the Entity Views Attachment (EVA) module to insert a view as a display mode field. While this is certainly a robust approach, it adds a lot of processing overhead with the rendered entities, so you definitely want to cache the results of that as well.

p.s. You might get faster/more responses over at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/